# Can be certificate read out from registry without booting windows?

Tags: certificate, registry

Is it posible to read a certificate out from registry without booting windows, if you know login credentials and computer name.
I have writen a little tool which automate copying of data from standard windows user folders like my document.

This tool is then part of live linux distro which we use to copy users data when we making transition from previous to our IT. Only problem is that we can't get certifikates this way and i'd like to solve this, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This program can read from the Windows registry Hives under Linux: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ .

I don't know where the certificates are stored or in what format, but they're in the registry somewhere.  Check MSDN for information or do a registry diff before and after storing a cert.

Betcha they're DER-encoded binary keys.